# Batch replace multiple files in multiple subfolders

Tags: batch-file

I just joined stackoverflow because you people are awesome.  So I have been batch scripting for a year now, yes I know this is as old as "Gone with the Wind" but I have no choice.

My **BATCH** issue is this. I need to compare c:\folder1\ `*.bat`  with  E:\Folder4\ `*.bat`and only return those ".bat" files which match up.  I can easily achieve this with this code....

*for /R c:\folder1\ %%i in (*.bat) do if exist "E:\Folder4\%%~nxi" (echo %%~ni )

I can then proceed to do as I like which for the most part is backup and replace.  However, I just ran into something interesting.  I now need to perform the same operation but like so:

Compare files in c:\folder1*.bat with

> E:\Folder4\subfolder1\ *.bat
>   E:\Folder4\subfolder2\ *.bat
>   E:\Folder4\subfolder3\ *.bat
>   E:\Folder4\subfolder4\ *.bat
>   E:\Folder4\subfolder5\ *.bat
>   E:\Folder4\subfolder6\ *.bat

and so on.

MY **BATCH** question is how can I compare what's in c:\folder1*.bat and see if its also in each E:\Folder4\subfolder?  Once that's done I also need to replace what's in E:\Folder4\subfolder with matching files from c:\folder1*.bat.  I've done this in other languages but no clue how to in **batch**.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, then something like this may work:

```
for %%i in (
     "D:\Folder4\subfolder1\*.bat"
     "D:\Folder4\subfolder2\*.bat"
     "D:\Folder4\subfolder3\*.bat"
     "D:\Folder4\subfolder4\*.bat"
     "D:\Folder4\subfolder5\*.bat"
     "D:\Folder4\subfolder6\*.bat"
    ) do XCOPY /U /Y "C:\folder1\*.bat" "%%i"
```

Basically the `XCOPY` command has the options I believe you require.

**EDIT**

My understanding grows :P ...this perhaps is more what you seek:

```
@echo off
for /r D:\Folder4\ %%i in (*.bat) do (
for /r C:\folder\ %%j in (*.bat) do (
if %%~ni == %%~nj XCOPY /U /Y "%%j" "%%i"
)
)
pause
```

Comment: Thanks Chris.  Yes that's the idea but I need a for loop because "D:\Folder4\" grows frequently and I don't know where in "D:\Folder4\" the ".bat" file I am looking for is.  Here is what I cam up with and it works but for some odd reason duplicates some results but not all which is weird..

for /R C:\folder1 %%a in (*.dtsx) do (
 for /R D:\Folder4 %%b in (*.dtsx) do (
  if %%~na == %%~nb  echo %%~nb
   )
   )

maybe /b?  Oh and the echo within the loop is just to confirm i found the correct ".bat".

Comment: Hello havek! ...See **EDIT** in my answer :D

Comment: Yes that's what I already have and yes the xcopy will do the job although I have been using plain ole "copy".  Now, last question. Have you echoed out this routine?  Why does it duplicate results?  So lets say you have 6 ".bat" files (what I am testing with) it repeats that it found 3 of them 3 times each.  Any idea why?  Oh, added info, I have 1 ".bat" in 1 folder, 2 different ".bat" in a 2nd folder, 3 different ".bat" in a 3rd folder.  the last folder is where I get the repeats

Comment: Chris never mind.  Some brainiac created subfolders in the "D:\Folder4\subfolder(x)" path which contain duplicate files.  These are the ones that I have been seeing as duplicates in the routine the entire time!!!!!!!!   Ahhhhhh!!!!  Anyways, thanks for all your help.  I still awarded you the "answered" points.

Comment: No problem havek, glad you found the reason for the duplicates. :) ...give that "brainiac" a clip 'round the earhole! :P

Comment: Added info for anyone reading.  Since we have a "one" to "many" file structure, in order for me to match files exactly, remember I have duplicate files on the many side, I had to do the following: "folder\subfolder\filename.ext" == "folder\subfolder\filename.ext".  In order to do this I had to add the "setlocal enabledelayedexpansion" then set apath=%%i then set apath=%apath:~10,25% (to set variable in for loop.  did this for both paths. the other path was bpath), then I did the compare as so !apath! == !bpath!.  This eliminated all duplicates and matched each file perfectly..  Cheers